# Operate only on a subset of buffer in OpenCL kernel

Tags: opencl, numerical-methods, pyopencl

Newbie to OpenCL here. I'm trying to convert a numerical method I've written to OpenCL for acceleration. I'm using the [PyOpenCL](https://mathema.tician.de/software/pyopencl/) package as I've written this once in Python already and as far as I can tell there's no compelling reason to use the C version. I'm all ears if I'm wrong on this, though.

I've managed to translate over most of the functionality I need in to OpenCL kernels. My question is on how to (properly) tell OpenCL to ignore my boundary/ghost cells. The reason I need to do this is that my method (for example) for point `i` accesses cells at `[i-2:i+2]`, so if `i=1`, I'll run off the end of the array. So - I add some extra points that serve to prevent this, and then just tell my algorithm to only run on points `[2:nPts-2]`. It's easy to see how to do this with a `for` loop, but I'm a little more unclear on the 'right' way to do this for a kernel.

Is it sufficient to do, for example (pseudocode)

```
__kernel void myMethod(...) {
    gid = get_global_id(0);

    if (gid < nGhostCells || gid > nPts-nGhostCells) {
        retVal[gid] = 0;
    }

    // Otherwise perform my calculations
}
```

or is there another/more appropriate way to enforce this constraint?

Answer (score 0):

It looks sufficient.

Branching is same for nPts-nGhostCells*2 number of points and it is predictable if nPts and nGhostCells are compile-time constants. Even if it is not predictable, sufficiently large nPts vs nGhostCells (1024 vs 3) should not be distinctively slower than zero-branching version, except the latency of "or" operation. Even that "or"  latency must be hidden behind array access latency, thanks to thread level parallelism.

At those "break" points, mostly 16 or 32 threads would lose some performance and only for several clock cycles because of the lock-step running of SIMD-like architectures.

If you happen to code some chaotic branching, like data-driven code path, then you should split them into different kernels(for different regions) or sort them before the kernel so that average branching between neighboring threads are minimized.